# How to restrict IP address to access RabbitMQ

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I had set up `rabbitmq` server on a remote machine, now I want to restrict the client (producer/consumer) based on IP address to connect to `rabbitmq`.
where consumers and producers are on different networks. Only allowed consumer/producer can publish/subscribe to queue. How to achieve this.

I had implemented simple producer/consumer code in nodejs `aqmp` library which works properly. Also, I had enabled the `auth_backend_ip_range` library on `rabbitmq` server.

But I don't know how to set only specific producer and consumer IP to connect it.

Comment: if there is not so much consumers/produces, you can setup firewall to allow specific ips or IP ranges to connect to your rabbitmq server

Comment: where do i need to specify these firewall rules. that only ip A can connect to queue and only ip B can consume to queue.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283877/restrict-access-to-rabbitmq-via-ip

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Restrict access to RabbitMQ via IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283877/restrict-access-to-rabbitmq-via-ip)

Comment: Please see this [Restrict Access to RabbitMQ Based on IP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41283877/restrict-access-to-rabbitmq-via-ip)

Comment: [
{rabbit, [
    {tcp_listeners, [5672]},
    {auth_backends, [
        {rabbit_auth_backend_internal,
        [rabbit_auth_backend_internal, rabbit_auth_backend_ip_range]
        }
    ]
    }
]},
{rabbitmq_auth_backend_ip_range, [
    {tag_masks,
        [{'customtag', [<<"::FFFF:172.xx.xx.xxx">>]}]},
    {default_masks, [<<"::0/0">>]}
]}
].                  Yes. I tried this but it still accepting connections from other networks. I had updated my IP address in above code.